# Getting "ValueError: A PythonObject is not attached to a node" even when wrapped in try/except block but this works fine if run in Nuke Script editor

Tags: python, nuke

My question is Foundary Nuke specific.

I have a tab added to Project Settings, that contains some data I can later access via the root node. Now since I have callback invoked by a checkbox knob I added to enable disable a custom knob I added to that tab I added to Project Settings Panel. It works fine. The problem is when I close nuke I get error:

```
Traceback (most  recent call last):
File "/system/runtime/plugins/nuke/callbacks.py", line 127, in knobChanged
    _doCallbacks(knobChangeds)
File "/system/runtime/plugins/nuke/callbacks.py", line 44, in _doCallbacks
  for f in list:
ValueError: A PythonObject is not attached to a node
```

Now this error happens if I have a callback function added to the checkbox knob like this:

my_callbacks.py

```
import nuke

def on_checkbox_clicked():
    try:
        root_node = nuke.root()
        if not root_node:
            return
    except ValueError as er:
        print(er)

nuke.addKnobChanged(on_checkbox_clicked, nodeClass='Root', node=nuke.root())
nuke.addonScriptClose(lambda: nuke.removeKnobChanged(on_checkbox_clicked, nodeClass-'Root', node=nuke.root())
```

but if I create a grade node named Grade1 and run the below code in script editor it works fine.

```
try:
    node = nuke.toNode('Grade1') 
    nuke.delete(node)
    node.fullname() # <-- should throw error
except ValueError:
    print(error caught.)
```

Comment: certainly seems like an internal nuke issue. which nuke are you running? I know 11 and 12 will almost always spit out some kind of python error on close - either threading or something like this.

Comment: in the above example which works fine when Using Grade node, but after some experimentation I have realized that this issue is only with the root node.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly seems like an internal nuke issue. Which nuke are you running? I know 11 and 12 will almost always spit out some kind of python error on close - either threading or something like this.

If your my_callbacks.py is being loaded by init/menu, try just adding the callback to the root node itself (rather than the global knob change process) with `node.knob('knob_changed').setValue(YOUR CODE in string format)`

In this case of course, the knob changed code will only fire on the Root node, and you'll have to run that `setValue` code in each script you want. You might be able to use init/menu and another callback (`onScriptLoad`) to accomplish that.

Comment: okay, so I have a multiline linedit which I need to enable using a checkbox knob which is connected in the callback, both of these checkbox knob and multiline lineedit sites in the tab on project setting panel which is accessible by pressing **S** key, I can give it a try to put the code in `setValue` but I am skeptical unless I try and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `nuke.thisNode()` in your callback?
and reduce to `nuke.addKnobChanged(on_checkbox_clicked, nodeClass='Root')`

Like you I'm confused by this error, sometimes it appears but it shouldn't and when it should appear it doesn't...